# Regex to change all text to lowercase but leave out parts of text that start and end in a specific way

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

Is there a way to change all text to lowercase except the words that start with a specific combination of letters ("ABC") and end with a white space (dots, hyphen, underscore can be within?
Preserve capitalization in words like "ABCkjkJ.90_1 " or "ABC-12_OLL " but lowercase everything else?

Find:

(I have no idea)

```
[^ABC][\s]$
```

Replace with:

```
\L$1
```

Also, how should I delete all punctuation from the rest of the text (not the ones starting with ABC)?

Comment: Regexes are not language agnostic. `\L` and other case changing operators are not supported in many regex libraries. Other features you may need for this task may differ from regex library to regex library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem boils down to matching words that don't start with `ABC`. Because words in your string can contain dots and hyphens, which aren't word characters, we can't use `\b` to determine the start of a word, unfortunately - instead, *match* the preceding space (or the beginning of the string) with

```
(?: |^)
```

and then negative lookahead for `abc`, and match as many words, dots, or hyphens as possible:

```
(?: |^)(?!abc)[\w.-]*
```

Then, lowercase every full match.

https://regex101.com/r/QSShDu/1

Example, for input:

```
Baz Buzz ABCkjkJ.90_1 ABC-12_OLL Foo Bar
```

you get

```
baz buzz ABCkjkJ.90_1 ABC-12_OLL foo bar
```

If the `ABC` part always occurs at the beginning of the string, then it's a lot easier - just capture the first word in a group, then capture the rest of the string in a group, and capitalize the rest of the string:

```
([\w.-]*)(.+)
```

replace with

```
\1\L\2
```

https://regex101.com/r/QSShDu/2

Comment: Thanks!
If that matters, the "ABC***" string is always at the beginning of the line. Each line invariably starts with "ABC" and gibberish characters that need to maintain their capitalization, but the rest of the line contains the text that needs to be lowercase.

Comment: Thank you so much! One last thing, if I'm not getting too impertinent: how do I delete all punctuation except the apostrophe from the rest of the string?
Replace - sth like ([\w.-]*)(\W\S)?
And what do I replace it with?

Comment: Put every punctuation character you want to remove in a character set, then replace every occurrence with the empty string. eg `[._-]`

Comment: I decided to forget about the apostrophe.
tried ([\w.-]*)([[:punct:]]) 

replaced with 

\1\[._-]\2. That didn't work

Comment: You shouldn't try matching word characters, only match the punctuation marks you want to remove, in a character set. eg `[._-]` to remove all dots, underscores, and dashes

Comment: Where is [._-]  to be used?
I was trying to edit the second group from your expression (thank you!) so that it captures all punctuation that's not in the ([\w.-]*) and then somehow remove the second group.

Comment: The `[._-]` (or `[._-]+` if you want) should be the *entire* regular expression https://regex101.com/r/QSShDu/3

Comment: Sorry for being so persistent, but it's still the case that I don't want the "ABC***" part to be altered.

Comment: If you only want to replace punctuation in the latter part of the string, then perform the replace-with-empty-string action above only on the second group extracted from the first regex

Comment: That's what I don't know how to do :)
([\w.-]*)([._-])

And the substitution is (\1\(What should it be that removes the punctuation???)\2)

Comment: It depends on your environment - you'll have to extract the second group and manipulate it while replacing (or just concatenate afterwards with the first group). For example, in Javascript, `str => str.replace(/([\w.-]*)(.+)/, (first, rest) => first + rest.toLowerCase().replace(/[._-]/g, ''))`

Comment: This is getting to sound like a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)...

Comment: I know. I cleaned it with Python a long time ago to go ahead with the task itself. But I need to know how to  prepare the text (lowercase and rid it of punctuation) with regex which I never used. Thought if I could get help singling out ABCetc, it would be easy for me to deduce how to clean out the punctuation from the the second set, which is all there is, but I kinda can't do even that.  Ok, thanks for your time, I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: You can manipulate it after you extract each group from the match in Python, eg `m = re.compile(r'(f\w+) (b\w+)').search('foo bar')`, then `m.group(1)` holds the initial string and `m.group(2)` holds the second, change the second as you need to (like remove punctuation and turn lower-case), then concatenate with the first again

Comment: I just separated the part of each line from its beginning to the int(line.find(' ')) and manipulated the rest. I wanted to see how to do it outside of Python. Getting the actual result is not an issue for me, the very user-unfriendly regex was :)